# Не работает код игры "Угадай число" для бота в ТГ Python pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Никак не могу написать код для игры в угадай число для бота, код пишу в отдельном файле(не главном), чтобы потом вызвать его функцией, вот код игры:

```
import random
import time


def random_guesses(message,bot):
# число попыток угадать
    guesses_made = 0
    guess = 0

# получаем имя пользователя из консольного ввода
    name = str(message.chat.first_name)

# получаем случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до 30
    number = random.randint(1, 30)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{0}, я загадал число между 1 и 30. Сможешь угадать?'.format(name))
    time.sleep(1)

# пока пользователь не превысил число разрешенных попыток - 6
    while guesses_made < 6:
        
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи число")
        
        try:
            guess = int(message.text)
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неверный ввод. Введите число")

        
    # увеличиваем счетчик числа попыток
        guesses_made += 1

        if guess < number:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число меньше того, что я загадал.')

        elif guess > number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число больше загаданного мной.')

    if guess == number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ух ты, {0}! Ты угадал мое число, использовав {1} попыток!'.format(name, guesses_made))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А вот и не угадал! Я загадал число {0}'.format(number))
```

Вызов функции идёт с главного файла кодом:

```
if message.text.lower() == "Угадай число":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, conf_games.random_guesses(message, bot))
```

Бот идёт по циклу не принимая сообщения, кажется надо как то добавить приём сообщений из главного файла в цикл, но не понимаю как это сделать.
Когда пишу боту "Угадай число" игра запускается, но бот пишет вот это, я даже ответить не успеваю, он строчит без остановки:
https://ibb.co/rGqLb2c
В консоли вот это:
https://ibb.co/pJLp2SF
Помогите доработать что бы игра работала, заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Вы не принимаете новое сообщение пользователя, а просто бегаете по циклу 6 раз и сравниваете старое сообщение с загаданным числом

Comment: Как исправить подскажите пожалуйста, буду благодарен

Comment: @НикитаКотов дополните свой вопрос, путём правки, попытками сделать то что требуется. и на основе ваших попыток можно будет сказать где именно ошибка.

Comment: @D. Violet я добавил правку, но про это все я уже сказал и скрины выложил, не понимаю что ещё можно добавить, вроде все описал, в комментариях описано возможное решение, но тоже не совсем понятно как исправить

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает код для игры в угадай число для бота в тг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181807/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ох, общими усилиями:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message, where_call=None):
    if where_call is None:
        global number
        number = random.randint(1, 30)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сможешь угадать число между 1 и 30?')
        attempt = 1
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda message: random_number(message, attempt))

    elif where_call == 'not_digit':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'только числа')
        attempt = 1
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda message: random_number(message, attempt))


def random_number(message, attempt):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        n = int(message.text)
        if attempt < 6:
            attempt += 1
            if n < number:
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'мало\nещё')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda message: random_number(message, attempt))

            elif n > number:
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'много\nещё')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda message: random_number(message, attempt))
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'угадал, с {} попытки!'.format(attempt - 1))
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'попытки исчерпаны\nзагаданное число {0}'.format(number))
    else:
        welcome(message, where_call='not_digit')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: столкнулся с проблемой, что если нужно передать во функцию указанную в `register_next_step_handler` текст полученный в "первой функции", то через лямбду не сработает. решение нашёл тут https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/72#issuecomment-690850820. `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_bet, blogger)`, т.е. `bot.register_next_step_handler("bot.send_message", func, *arg)`

Comment: поправка к моему комментарию, всё работает если нужно передать текст из "первой" во "вторую" функцию, если использовать `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda message: func_2(message,*arg))` именно `lambda message:`! `lambda x:` будет заменять message.text