# Telegram-bot: игра "Угадай число"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telebot

Я программирую не так давно и очень  хотелось бы попробовать написать небольшого игрового *Telegram* бота.

В планах было создание, собственно, игры *"угадай число"* и создание ответов бота на некоторые сообщения. Представлял я себе это очень легко, но когда скачал библиотеку понеслась нервотрепка...

Были выявлены следующие проблемы при тесте кода:

1. При запуске игры возникает ошибка `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'игра'`, т.к. видимо строка `'игра'` попадает в переменную `guess`, чего быть не должно.
2. При введении строки `'привет'` или `'как дела'` бот не отвечает. Если же функции `digitgames` и `send_texts` поменять местами, то бот успешно отвечает, но запуск игры при этом не работает, причем ошибку нигде не выдает.

Вот код *(токен бота скрыт специально)*:

```
import telebot
import random


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def digitgames(message):
    if message.text.lower()=='игра':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Игра "угадай число"!\nКоличество попыток: 5')
        digit=random.randint(1,10)
        counter=5
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Готово! Загадано число от 1 до 10!')
        while counter>0:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число')
            guess=int(message.text)
            if guess==digit:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ура! Ты угадал число! Это была цифра:', digit)
                break
            else:
                counter-=1
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно, осталось попыток:', counter)
    

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_texts(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну привет)')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дела':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хорошо')
   
bot.polling()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182016/234134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, в PyTelegramBotAPI (и не только) весь функционал бота строится на декораторах. В вашем же случае вы запихнули ответ на 'как дела' и 'привет' в одну функцию, что не совсем хорошо если рассуждать со стороны эстетики языка Python, каждая функция дожна отвечать за определенный фнукционал, их можно было отделить в отдельные функции и указать в декораторе, определенные условия при которых срабатывала бы функция. То есть вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "привет")
def command_text_hi(m):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Ну привет)")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "как дела")
def command_text_dela(m):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "хорошо")
```

Такая же проблема и с функцией digitgames:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "игра")
def digitgames(message):
    attempt = 5
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Игра "угадай число"!\nКоличество попыток: {attempt}')
```

Во вторых, у вас два одинковых декоратора: `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`, из-за этого у вас бот не хотел реагировать на слова 'как дела' и 'привет'. То есть если у вас будет два определенных условии в декораторах, и сообщение пользывателя бота будет попадать под эти два условия, то будет срабатывать только первый декоратор, давайте возьмем за основу ваш пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def digitgames(message):
    if message.text.lower()=='игра':
        print("Gamee")
    else:
        print("Noting else")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_texts(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну привет)')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дела':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хорошо')
```

Как видите у нас есть две фнукции с декораторами, и в обеих декортаорах указано чтобы обе функции срабатывали на тип контента text (текст). Допустим вы напишите боту "привет", то по идее бот должен ответит вам "Ну привет)", но он вам ответит "Noting else". А почему? А потому что, функция digitgames стоит первой и его декоратор срабатывает на любой текст так же как и второй декоратор фнукции send_texts, но так как digitgames стоит первой и content_types=['text'] сообщении является True, то соотвественно вторая фнукция уже не срабатыватает.

В третих, что это такое?

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ура! Ты угадал число! Это была цифра:', digit)
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно, осталось попыток:', counter)
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Почему digit и counter у вас через запятую отделён от основного текста сообщени? send_message - это обычная функция, и она как любая другая функция принимает определеные аргументы, это вам не print(), где можно бесконечно указывать аргументы и все они будут восприниматся как текст:

```
>>> print("123", "456")                                                                                                   
123 456
```

Функция send_message в целом принимает много аргументов. Самые главные из них chat_id и text, chat_id вы верно указали - message.chat.id, а вот text не совсем коректно, вот правильный пример:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ура! Ты угадал число! Это была цифра: {digit}') # C помощью f-string, можно еще с помощью format
```

В четвортых, разработка бота это вам не халам-балам, хорошо что вы используете PyTelegramBotAPI, есть библиотека aiogram, это настоящии ад, она асинхронная, а чтобы понять ассинхронность нужно достаточно хорошо понимать Python (aiogram - это PyTelegramBotAPI на стеройдах).

`guess=int(message.text)`, `Cтрока 'игра' попадает в переменную guess, чего быть не должно.` - В разработке Телеграмм бота нету фнукции input(), есть кое-что похожее, но работает она совсем по другому принципу - bot.register_next_step_handler. Посмотрите вот этот пример: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Вот сообвственно ваш пофикшенный код:

```
import random
import telebot
from telebot import types
import logging

API_TOKEN = 'BOT API TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


storage = dict()

def init_storage(user_id):
    storage[user_id] = dict(attempt=None, random_digit=None)

def set_data_storage(user_id, key, value):
    storage[user_id][key] = value

def get_data_storage(user_id):
    return storage[user_id]

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "привет")
def command_text_hi(m):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Ну привет)")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "как дела")
def command_text_dela(m):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "хорошо")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "игра")
def digitgames(message):
    init_storage(message.chat.id) ### Инициализирую хранилище

    attempt = 5
    set_data_storage(message.chat.id, "attempt", attempt)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Игра "угадай число"!\nКоличество попыток: {attempt}')

    random_digit=random.randint(1, 10)
    print(random_digit)

    set_data_storage(message.chat.id, "random_digit", random_digit)
    print(get_data_storage(message.chat.id))
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Готово! Загадано число от 1 до 10!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_digit_step)

def process_digit_step(message):
    user_digit = message.text
    
    if not user_digit.isdigit():
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Вы ввели не цифры, введите пожалуйста цифры')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_digit_step)
            return

    attempt = get_data_storage(message.chat.id)["attempt"]
    random_digit = get_data_storage(message.chat.id)["random_digit"]

    if int(user_digit) == random_digit:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ура! Ты угадал число! Это была цифра: {random_digit}')
        init_storage(message.chat.id) ### Очищает значения из хранилище
        return
    elif attempt > 1:
        attempt-=1
        set_data_storage(message.chat.id, "attempt", attempt)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Неверно, осталось попыток: {attempt}')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_digit_step)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы проиграли!')
        init_storage(message.chat.id) ### Очищает значения из хранилище
        return
            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.skip_pending = True
    bot.polling()
```

Совет: никогда не используйте глобальные переменные в ботах, я в примере реализовал костыль в виде функции init_storage, set_data_storage и get_data_storage заместо глобальных переменных.

[image: Скриншот успешной работы бота]

RTFM и Удачи!

Comment: лайк за описание что да как, но можно проще - см. комментарии к вопросу

Comment: @Violet, ваш пример классный, но вы используете глобальные переменные, это как раз и проблема. Я провел небольшой эксперемент, зашел с одного аккаунта в бот и вызвал комманду /start, бот загадал мне цифру 15, зашел с второго аккаунта и вызвал команду бота /start, бот перезаписывает предедущию цифру 15 на 30, и в итоге получается что рандомное цифра будет у всех пользывателей одинаково, и будет менятся после кадого /start нового пользывателя.

Comment: согласен, глобалки зло, но и код не для прода)

Comment: @ZhymabekRoman Спасибо вам! Только начинаю и большая часть разъяснений ясна, пытался поэкспериментировать с вашим первым советом и запихнуть два разных ответа в разные функции. Как и учили:
'@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_texts1(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_texts2(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'как дела':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Xорошо')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)'
Но срабатывает только первая функция